# How to styling html elements in php?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to use HTML codes in PHP codes. like this:

```php
<?php
   if ($A == 1){
      echo "<div style="background-color:#fff;">Hi bro</div>";
   }
?>
```

I have an error in styling.
Please answer me❤

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes inside the string.

Comment: *"I have an error in styling"* - No, you have an error in PHP syntax.  You can use single-quotes for the PHP string literal, or escape the double-quotes within your string literal, or not use a string literal at all and move the HTML to outside the PHP code, or any number of different approaches.